# Updated to Xcode 10.1, now my app is asking for microphone permission?

Tags: xcode

I updated to Xcode 10.1 (10B61) yesterday, and now my app, which doesn't use the microphone at all, is suddenly asking for microphone permission in the simulator. Haven't had a chance to try it on device.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 3):

I've the same problem. Have you implemented the siri shortcuts?

edit: from apple:

> On macOS 10.14, Simulator might prompt for Microphone access at launch
> or when first interacting with the microphone in a simulator (for
> example, by using Siri). If you decline permissions, simulator audio
> sessions will not be able to use audio input of any kind, regardless
> of the permissions granted inside a simulator. Use the macOS System
> Preferences, Security & Privacy preference pane to change this
> setting.
>
> Your application must still be granted Microphone permission inside
> the simulator as well. macOS applies its permission policy to
> Simulator application as a whole, across all simulator runtime
> versions and all applications inside a simulator. Each simulator
> applies permission policies to individual applications just like
> devices. (40113388)

Comment: No, I haven't implemented siri shortcuts. But thank you for that Apple quote, that at least points toward turning it off in System Preferences.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these settings seem to fix the issue for me, and I'm not making use of the microphone in my app... so weird.

Answer (score 1):

My evidence is currently unfounded, but on experiencing this issue I am wondering if the incorporation of the google ads framework in my app is causing this.  Is big brother at google listening...?

Comment: Anecdotally the prompt started appearing for us right around when we added Google's Firebase. For some reason the prompt has stopped recently. Maybe if you update your 3rd party frameworks the prompt issue will be fixed for you also.

Comment: FWIW, I'm not using any Google products in my app. That said, I do have two dependencies. Perhaps they need updating.

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely normal.

The SIMULATOR is itself a MacOS application, and as a MacOS application, it needs permission to use the MacOS microphone. That has nothing to do with your iOS app running on the simulator, which might or might not need permission to use the simulated microphone.

Give the simulator permission to access the MacOS microphone and you're fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately, that has not been my experience. Every time I run my app in the simulator it again asks for microphone access. I have now granted that access hundreds of times. None of this happened before updating to Xcode 10. The message I get is NOT that the simulator wants access, it's that my app wants access.

When I go to system prefs on my computer, it shows that Xcode has requested access to the microphone, and that it has been granted. It never shows that Simulator has requested access.

Anyway, it is new to Xcode 10, for myself and the others here.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to macOS 10.14.4 and XCode 10.2 this problem is finally solved. The microphone permission is asked only once from now on.